# Browser automation handling Basic Authorization login prompt

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, browser, automation

I'm trying to automate data entry using selnium in chorme but after each click on the website I'm getting a login prompt which I want to ignore for proceeding to next step.

it's the login page which I have to go through. I have to use website login( which is in the background ). I can only go ahead with login process after dismissing the login prompt. Is it possible to dismiss login prompt using `driver.get("")`"? as I know that we can use `driver.get(f"https://{username}:{password}@website.com")` for direct login.

`driver.switch_to.alert.dismiss()` I have tried this but code is not able to detect any alert on the browser as the pop up which I'm getting is Basic Authorization login prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can even use autoIT to handle the authentication pop up. Other alerts are generated at the client side and that is why you will be able to switch to the alert. But in the case of authentication pop up, server requests you to provide credentials for authentication purpose.